# MYSQL - Selecting existing users who have not made an entry in the last 3 months, but have made an entry within the last 6 months

Tags: mysql, subquery

After several hours of searching I'm finally giving in and asking for help. I've found something that gets me close, but doesn't seem to be working properly.

Basically looking for users who uses us between 3-6 months ago, but haven't in the last 3 months.

For the sake of the example lets say I have two tables named event(id, clientFK, insertion_date, officeFK) and client(id, name):

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.id, e.insertion_date, c.name
FROM event e
LEFT JOIN client c ON c.id = e.clientFK
WHERE e.id NOT IN (   
SELECT e.id
FROM event e
WHERE e.insertion_date
BETWEEN (
NOW( ) - INTERVAL 3
MONTH
)
AND NOW( )
)
AND e.insertion_date > ( NOW( ) - INTERVAL 6
MONTH )
AND officeFK =1
ORDER BY e.insertion_date DESC
```

**UPDATE***
id is just an auto incrementing column so obviously it would never show up using the logic above. I meant to search for the clientFK in the event table. Based off the first response below I came up with this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.clientFK, e.insertion_date, c.name
FROM event e
LEFT JOIN client c ON c.id = e.clientFK
WHERE e.clientFK NOT IN (
  SELECT e.clientFK FROM event e
  WHERE e.insertion_date > (NOW() - INTERVAL 3 DAY)
)
AND e.insertion_date BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 3 DAY) AND (NOW() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
AND officeFK =1
ORDER BY e.insertion_date DESC
```

However, even when narrowing the NOT IN subquery to just 3 days I'm still returning 0 rows. Changing NOT IN to IN also results in 0 rows returned. There are thousands of rows in my events table where the clientFK is "NOT IN" the last 3 days. I've got to be doing something wrong somewhere.

CORRECT CODE BELOW:

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.id, e.insertion_date, c.name
FROM event e
JOIN client c ON c.id = e.clientFK
WHERE e.clientFK NOT IN (
  SELECT e.clientFK FROM event e
  WHERE e.insertion_date > (NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
)
AND e.insertion_date < (NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
AND insertion_date > (NOW() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
AND e.officeFK = 1
ORDER BY e.insertion_date DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this. But I think you're close. You don't seem to have the date range correct for 3-6 months in your primary query. You were checking for anything from 6 months until now. That doesn't match the spec of the OP - users of an event 3-6 months ago, but not within the last 3 months. Logically it seems the same, but try this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.id, e.insertion_date, c.name
FROM event e
JOIN client c ON c.id = e.clientFK
WHERE e.clientFK NOT IN (
  SELECT e.clientFK FROM event e
  WHERE e.insertion_date > (NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
)
AND e.insertion_date BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH) AND (NOW() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
AND e.officeFK = 1
ORDER BY e.insertion_date DESC
```

Comment: You are correct on my out date range. I've corrected that, but I'm still returning 0 rows. See the update I made to the original post above.

Comment: I've updated my code. Break the query into parts and check the output. That is run the sub-query only and see what it finds. I've also dropped the `LEFT JOIN` to just `JOIN`.

Comment: Thanks Jason...you put me on the right track. Apparently the insertion_date didn't like the 'BETWEEN' operator. I switched it to < > and it worked perfect. I've update my code above. Again, thanks a lot for the help. I really appreciate it!

Comment: Interesting. What is the columns data type out of curiosity?

Comment: Datetime - Do you think that might be the issue? I use these columns with BETWEEN in other queries throughout the site, but for whatever reason they wouldn't work here.